# How to show a different item between two different items in a recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat, adapter

I am working on a chat app, And there are two types of views, one is for incoming messages and another is for outgoing messages. So I differentiate them by view type as 0 and 1. So it is working awesome but now I want to add another view for the date as a header like [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/B2ZEK2W9KdEZnTHr8). So for this, I made another view type as 2 but It replaces it with the message view. So, How can I show the 3rd view between the 2 views?

This is how I create the `ViewHolder`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder {
        return if (position == 1) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_outgoing_message, parent, false)
            ViewHolder(view)
        } else if (position == 0) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_incoming_message, parent, false)
            ViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_show_time_chat, parent, false)
            ViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
```

This is the way I differentiate the `ViewType`

```
 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (mChatList[position].getSender() == currentUserID) {
            1
        }
        else if (mChatList[position].getMessageDate() == getTheRecentMessageDate(position)){
            2
        }
        else {
            0
        }
    }
```

This is to get the difference between dates

```
private fun getTheRecentMessageDate(position: Int): String {
        val lastMessagePosition = position - 1
        //return the 1st message if messages chat thread is empty
        val chat = mChatList[if (lastMessagePosition <= 0) 0 else lastMessagePosition]
        //get and return the sender of the last message
        return chat.getMessageDate()
    }
```

And Finally applying it in `BindViewHolder`

```
if (mChatList[position].getMessageDate() == getTheRecentMessageDate(position)){
            holder.showDateTv?.text = getTheRecentMessageDate(position)
        }
```

Comment: you might find it easier to make the "Message Date" view part of the sender message layout ...  this will enable a one-to-one mapping between your `mChatList` and the Recycler rows

Comment: @CSmith I know that and I already have tried it, but when I swipe a message to reply, the date view also swipes with that.

Comment: Your adapter needs to represent a mapping of your chat messages (e.g. 2 rows) to your Recycler (e.g. 3 rows).  Your `onCreateViewHolder`,  `getItemViewType`, and `onBindViewHolder` logic is way off.

Comment: @CSmith can you please explain it as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Your Adapter logic is flawed, you need to define a proper mapping from your data model (`mChatList`) to your RecyclerView.

For example, if your list of chat messages has two entries, you want a recycler with three rows.

Here is some roughed out pseudo-code, sorry this is Java, but you should get the idea:

```
    static final int VIEW_TYPE_SENDER = 0;
    static final int VIEW_TYPE_TIMESTAMP = 1;
    static final int VIEW_TYPE_REPLY = 2;

    public int getItemCount()
    {
      // One row for each chat message + one row for each pair of messages.
      // This logic possibly flawed for odd # of messages in mChatList
      return (mChatList.size() + (mChatList.size() / 2);
    } 
    
    public int getItemViewType (int position)
    {
        // modulo 3 to get the view type
        switch (position % 3)
        {
         case 0:
             return (VIEW_TYPE_SENDER);
         case 1:
            return (VIEW_TYPE_TIMESTAMP);
         case 2:
            return (VIEW_TYPE_REPLY);
        }
    }
    
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        switch (viewType)
        {
        case VIEW_TYPE_SENDER:
           // return a Sender viewholder...
        case VIEW_TYPE_REPLY:
           // return a Reply viewholder...
        case VIEW_TYPE_TIMESTAMP:
           // return a timestamp viewholder...
        }
     }
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        if (holder instanceof SenderHolder)
        {
            int chatMessage = (position / 3);
            // use mChatList[chatMessage] to get the data 
        }
        else if (holder instanceof ReplyHolder)
        {
            int chatMessage = (position / 3) + 1;
// use mChatList[chatMessage] to get the data
        }
        ...
    }
```

Please note this doesn't account for an odd number of chat messages, e.g. a Sender without a Reply, which must be normal.  This answer will hopefully point you in the right direction.